# Rapid Api- Skyscanner Flight Search gives 403 (Forbidden) error

Tags: api, http-status-code-403, skyscanner, rapidapi

I was using the free edition of that API for 20 days. There was no problem and status code was 200, I could fetch data . However, suddenly server started to response forbidden.

I have no idea what just happened, I tried to change my api key and nothing has changed. This time, server responses 429, which means 'too many request' with the new api-key. Anyone have an idea what can be the problem is ? I even tried with different accounts , every attempt was a fail for me. My subscription is free edition.  Also it says something like this as a response :

> Disabled partner with integration ID 27378

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bad news :

> Skyscanner decides to stop their API on RapidAPI it won't be available
> anymore.

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Skyscanner API endpoint is no longer available to RapidAPI service (as confirmed via email from the RapidAPI team).

You can use some other [Flight API](https://rapidapi.com/search/flight) available on RapidAPI Hub.